# Fail to connect to kubectl from client-go - /serviceaccount/token: no such file

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, client-go

I am using golang lib [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) to connect to a running local kubrenets. To start with I took code from the example: [out-of-cluster-client-configuration](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration).

Running a code like this:
`$ KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=localhost KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=6443 go run ./main.go` results in following error:

```
panic: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:

/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/
```

I am not quite sure which part of configuration I am missing. I've researched following links :

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/

But with no luck.
I guess I need to either let the client-go know which token/serviceAccount to use, or configure kubectl in a way that everyone can connect to its api.

Here's status of my kubectl though some commands results:

**$ kubectl config view**

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://localhost:6443
  name: docker-for-desktop-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-for-desktop-cluster
    user: docker-for-desktop
  name: docker-for-desktop
current-context: docker-for-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-for-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

**$ kubectl get serviceAccounts**

```
NAME        SECRETS   AGE
default     1         3d
test-user   1         1d
```

**$ kubectl describe serviceaccount test-user**

```
Name:                test-user
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   test-user-token-hxcsk
Tokens:              test-user-token-hxcsk
Events:              <none>
```

**$ kubectl get secret test-user-token-hxcsk -o yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0......=
  namespace: ZGVmYXVsdA==
  token: ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpTVXpJMU5pSX......=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: test-user
    kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 984b359a-6bd3-11e8-8600-XXXXXXX
  creationTimestamp: 2018-06-09T10:55:17Z
  name: test-user-token-hxcsk
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "110618"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/test-user-token-hxcsk
  uid: 98550de5-6bd3-11e8-8600-XXXXXX
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Comment: Could you call `go run ./main.go --kubeconfig /path/to/your/kubeconfig/file` and tell the result.

Comment: What I should put to config file ? Output of the 'kubectl config view' ?

Comment: I've tried the following: `$ kubectl config view > kubeconfig`, and then `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=localhost KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=6443 go run ./main.go --kubeconfig ./kubeconfig` and have the same error: 
`panic: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
`

Comment: Try to execute exactly that command without env variables.

Comment: @NickRak I am sorry correction: I was running this example - `Authenticating inside the cluster` - referencing the https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/main.go - this is the one that fail with error. The example `out-of-cluster-client-configuration` https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration - works fine for me

Comment: @shershen, the example you are using is supposed to be run inside a pod running in the cluster and not on host machines. Are you running this inside a pod?

Comment: @TarunLalwani you are right I am checking the right config to run inside the kluster

Comment: Could you provide output of command `kubectl describe pods $name_of_pod_where_you_run_client` I`m intrested in section mounted secret.

Comment: One of the possible reasons why you get this error is by the lack of `token` in your `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/` when inside a `Pod`. For example it could be cased by: `automountServiceAccountToken: false` in either `Pod` manifest or `ServiceAccount` manifest.

Comment: @shershen, could you please edit your original question, so that it matches your real intend. You are actually trying to use in-cluster-client-configuration, whereas you state opposite - "I took code from the example: out-of-cluster-client-configuration.". It's misleading the audience, and actually you have a dozen of correct hints and answers to choose from to solve your issue now. Please pick up the one that suits you the most, and close this thread.

Answer (score 1):

This answer could be a little outdated but I will try to give more perspective/baseline for future readers that encounter the same/similar problem.

**TL;DR**

The following error:

```golang
panic: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
```

is most likely connected with the lack of `token` in the `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` location when using **`in-cluster-client-configuration`**. Also, it could be related to the fact of using **`in-cluster-client-configuration`** code outside of the cluster (for example running this code directly on a laptop or in pure Docker container).

You can check following commands to troubleshoot your issue further (assuming this code is running inside a `Pod`):

- `$ kubectl get serviceaccount X -o yaml`:

  - look for: `automountServiceAccountToken: false`
- `$ kubectl describe pod XYZ`

  - look for: `containers.mounts` and `volumeMounts` where `Secret` is mounted

Citing the official documentation:

> #### Authenticating inside the cluster
>
> This example shows you how to configure a client with client-go to authenticate to the Kubernetes API from an application running **inside the Kubernetes cluster.**
>
> client-go uses the [Service Account token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#service-account-tokens) **mounted inside the Pod** at the `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` path when the `rest.InClusterConfig()` is used.
>
> -- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: client-go: Examples: in cluster client configuration](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration#authenticating-inside-the-cluster)*

If you are authenticating to the Kubernetes API with `~/.kube/config` you should be using the **`out-of-cluster-client-configuration`**.

---

#### Additional information:

I've added additional information for more reference on further troubleshooting when the code is run inside of a `Pod`.

- `automountServiceAccountToken: false`

> In version 1.6+, you can opt out of automounting API credentials for a service account by setting automountServiceAccountToken: false on the service account:
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ServiceAccount
> metadata:
>   name: go-serviceaccount
> automountServiceAccountToken: false
> ```
>
> In version 1.6+, you can also opt out of automounting API credentials for a particular pod:
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: sdk
> spec:
>  serviceAccountName: go-serviceaccount
>  automountServiceAccountToken: false
> ```
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Configure pod container: Configure service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server)*

- `$ kubectl describe pod XYZ`:

When the `servicAccount` token is mounted, the `Pod` definition should look like this:

```
<-- OMITTED --> 
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from go-serviceaccount-token-4rst8 (ro)
<-- OMITTED --> 
Volumes:
  go-serviceaccount-token-4rst8:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  go-serviceaccount-token-4rst8
    Optional:    false
```

If it's not:

```
<-- OMITTED --> 
    Mounts:         <none>
<-- OMITTED --> 
Volumes:            <none>
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Access authn authz: Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/)*

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, in case it helps you further debug it: the problem has nothing to do with Go or your code, and everything to do with the Kubernetes node not being able to get a token from the Kubernetes master.

In `kubectl config view`, `clusters.cluster.server` should probably point at an IP address that the *node* can reach.
It needs to access the CA, i.e., the master, in order to provide that token, and I'm guessing it fails to for that reason.
`kubectl describe <your_pod_name>` would probably tell you what the problem was acquiring the token.

Since you assumed the problem was Go/your code and focused on that, you neglected to provide more information about your Kubernetes setup, which makes it more difficult for me to give you a better answer than my guess above ;-)

But I hope it helps!